# any good sound designing memories through photos to share? 

Tags: design, equipment

recently updated my teams devblog with some sound designing times for the minigame Fatous Olous we made for a big website!

http://devblog.tsimpountiii.gr/sound-design-music-scoring/sound-designing-for-fatous-olous-flash-game/

check my pics and share your favorite moments! (thought that this kind of post was missed from this great website!) cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Recording car destruction for 007: Quantum of Solace game:

http://www.flickr.com/photos/chuckrussom/sets/72157623292496631/

Comment: What did you do about the noise of the lift?  RX?

Comment: The guy controlling it shut the engine off right as he dropped the car.  By the time they hit the ground, there was no noise from the lift.

Comment: @Chuck, John Fasal recorded some concrete drops for Live Free or Die Hard using the same technique. Got some great stuff, and very clean - no motors. 

Comment: @Jay, I worked with John on these car drops.  He is the man when it comes to this stuff.

Comment: @Chuck, Why wrap the mic stand with paper?

Comment: I have read the answer below, to protect against oil.

Answer (score 1):

looking for authentic running in the woods...

http://www.fonsschiedon.com/archives/921

Comment: hahah! its great! 

Answer (score 1):

Whilst browsing through my files, I found this little gem...got it off set on a shoot I was on and decided to keep it...I have EQ'd it a bit, removing the lows:

http://soundcloud.com/damaus/01-rain-against-windows-eq-intpers

Answer (score 1):

Two come to mind:

- [Over 11,000' altitude in the southern Sierra Nevada](http://www.flickr.com/photos/atomick/4981878136/-), recording high winds through rocks. Only a somewhat successful session, but memorable. Hiked down to camp as the sun set. No audio of this session online.
- [Around 6,000' altitude in the northern Sierra Nevada](http://www.flickr.com/photos/atomick/5282690031/), recording a marshland dawn chorus at 4:30am with the Nature Sound Society. The sounds from this session can be heard [here](http://soundcloud.com/noisejockey/amb-bird-dawnchorus-sierravalley-01).

Comment: @NoiseJockey Beautiful.  I hate New York City more now.

Answer (score 1):

Recording at Corkscrew Swamp in Naples Florida.  My brother is a sick photographer and he documented the day:

http://daveraphael.com/blog/christmas-swamp/

and the recordings are here:

http://sepulchra.com/blog/?p=835

Answer (score 0):

This was a funny session for a short film we did 2 years ago, called "Pedido Perdido" by Felipe F. Koeraus. We taped a Zoom H4 to a bicycle and went outside for some recording. Here are some photos, and the short film if you want to watch it and hear the bike sounds:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[youtube]Yj3dQDnAkvQ[/youtube]

Comment: very entertaining short, alansende

Comment: Thanks! The whole production process was very entertaining indeed